# Why does Samsung Magician constantly make the hard drive LED blink?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-11, usb-storage, samsung-ssd

I have a Samsung T7 Shield connected through USB Type C and I noticed that it was **constantly** blinking even though there was no access.

So after much trial, closing every single program and service, it turns out that Samsung Magician was the culprit, turning its service off immediately fixed the problem.

Why does it do that? Is this a known issue or something?

(FYI, asking here because there doesn't seem to be any support link in Samsung site, besides servicing.)

Comment: Are you very sure the USB drive is a Samsung drive?  Samsung Magician can act up on an non-Samsung drive.  I normally keep Magician turned off.

Comment: I normally use Magician with Samsung SSD drives.  So again turn it off if not needed in a particular circumstance.

Comment: Of course it is and is fully supported by Samsung Magician. Actually, it's the only way to update its firmware, which happened once at first power on.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Magician is not designed or for use on Hard Drives. That is likely why you are seeing the HDD LED blink like it does. That is, Magician is not supported on hard drives.

Accordingly, do not use Magician in a hard drive environment.

Use it only for its supported application.

Please see:   [Samsung Magician](https://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer-storage/magician/)

> While some of its features support Samsung-manufactured OEM SSDs and
> SSDs from other manufacturers, SSD Magician Software is designed and
> optimized specifically for Samsung-branded SSDs.
> ** Magician only shows features that are supported for the connected SSD. The features that appear may differ depending on the connected
> SSD.
> *** Magician does not work with SSDs connected via the SCSI controller interface.

Comment: As mentioned above, the drive is fully supported by Samsung Magician and it is the only way to update the firmware which happened on first power on. It's just that it makes that extremely annoying thing of blinking the drive LED all day long.